# How to access a public synonym in a function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, synonym

In a schema (Oracle 11g Database) , I can run (i.e. the user has the privilege to select from dba_tables):

`select count(*) from dba_tables where table_name = 'XXX' and owner = 'YYY';`

But when I tried to create a function in the same schema, I got "PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist":

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chk_table (p_owner IN varchar2, p_table_name IN varchar2) RETURN number IS
    v_count integer;
    BEGIN
    v_count := 0;
    select count(*) into v_count
    from dba_tables
    where table_name = p_table_name
    and owner = p_owner
    ;
    return v_count;
  END chk_table;
  /`

Errors for FUNCTION CHK_TABLE:
9/8      PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic SQL and invoker's rights to solve this problem.  An alternative is to directly grant access to DBA_TABLES to your account.

```
create or replace function chk_table(p_owner in varchar2, p_table_name in varchar2)
    return number authid current_user is
    v_count integer;
begin
    v_count := 0;
    execute immediate '
        select count(*)
        from dba_tables
        where table_name = :p_table_name
            and owner = :p_owner'
    into v_count
    using p_table_name, p_owner;

    return v_count;
end chk_table;
/
```

Compiled PL/SQL does not have access to objects granted to the owner through a role.  Dynamic SQL avoids the compile-time privilege check.  Invoker's rights, `authid current_user`, will use the caller's privileges, including role privileges, when it is called.

The privileges depend on your requirements.  As it stands, this function does not grant any additional privileges to users.  If you *want* it to give additional privileges to callers, then keep the function as you have it and directly grant SELECT access to your account.